# V8/Ignition: Print bytecode of just the top-level code of a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, bytecode

I know both D8 and Node.js have the options --print-bytecode to print the bytecode during execution and --print-bytecode-filter to limit which function I want printed. But is there any way to limit the printed bytecode only to the top-level code of a script instead of a specific function in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me help you help yourself:

(1) Use [source.chromium.org](https://source.chromium.org) to search for `FLAG_print_bytecode_filter`.

(2) Take a look at the code that handles the flag, in particular this snippet:

```cpp
  if (shared->is_toplevel()) {
    base::Vector<const char> filter =
        base::CStrVector(FLAG_print_bytecode_filter);
    return (filter.length() == 0) || (filter.length() == 1 && filter[0] == '*');
  }
```

(3) That's your answer: `--print-bytecode-filter=""` limits bytecode printing to the top-level code.